# setting up vitrual environment for deep learning on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to setup virtual environment for every deep learning project that i do locally on my laptop so that every package like numpy, matplotlib, opencv-python etc. i installed will be installed in that environment only not on my laptop globally. Now, the problem is i activate the virtual environment using `source ENV_NAME/bin/activate` and when i import libraries like cv2 in my notebook after installing cv2 in that environment setup, it says "
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`" please see the screenshots below. but when i deactivate that environment and install cv2 on my laptop globally and then try to import cv2, it works fine. Could someone please tell my why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I know about Pycharm, in which sometimes I see that venv is activated and the pip installs are done successfully, but interpreter is still set to a previous setting. Check your interpreter config and change it to the current venv, and if you see all installed libs there, then it should work fine.

Comment: i am using jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the kernel in Jupyter Notebook for the new modules to show up.

[image]

Comment: i did , still getting same error PS: i am also firing up jupyter notebook after i activate virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already found the solution, but I stumbled upon this blog and it answers most questions of the type: **I installed package X and now I can't import it in the notebook. Help!**

You can install the package directly in the jupyter notebook using:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install opencv-python
```

if using pip.

OR

```
# Install a conda package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} opencv-python
```

if using conda.

Head over to [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) for more details.